# Tensorflow: modify shape of placeholder when retrieving metagraph

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I trained a recurrent neural network (LSTM) and saved the weights and the metagraph. When I retrieve the metagraph for prediction, everything works perfectly as long as the sequence length is the same as during the training.

One of the benefits of LSTM is that the sequence length of the inputs can vary (for example, if inputs are letters forming a sentence, the length of the sentences can vary).

How can I change the sequence length of the inputs when retrieving the graph from a metagraph?

**More details with code:**

During training, I use placeholders `x` and `y` to feed the data. For prediction, I retrieve these placeholders but cannot manage to change their shape (from `[None, previous_sequence_length=100, n_input]`, to `[None, new_sequence_length=50, n_input]`).

In the file `model.py`, defining the architecture and placeholders:

```
 self.x = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, self.n_steps, self.n_input], name='x_input')
 self.y = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, self.n_classes], name='y_labels')
 tf.add_to_collection('x', self.x)
 tf.add_to_collection('y', self.y)
 ...

 def build_model(self):
     #using the placeholder self.x to build the model
     ...
     tf.split(0, self.n_input, self.x) # split input for RNN cell
     ...
```

In the file `prediction.py` where I retrieve the metagraph for prediction:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir=checkpoint_dir)
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(latest_checkpoint + '.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)
    x = tf.get_collection('x')[0]
    y = tf.get_collection('y')[0]
    ...
    sess.run(..., feed_dict={x: batch_x})
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128, 50, 2) for Tensor u'placeholders/x_input:0', which has shape '(?, 100, 2)'
```

NOTE: I manage to solve this problem when **not using metagraph** but rather reconstructing the model from scratch and loading only the saved weights (and not the metagraph).

**EDIT**: when replacing `self.n_steps` with `None` and modifying `tf.split(0, self.n_input, self.x)` with `tf.split(0, self.x.get_shape()[1], self.x)` I get the following error: `TypeError: Expected int for argument 'num_split' not Dimension(None).`

Comment: You typically can't change the shape of a tensor after the fact. However, one thing you can do is *not* fix the shape of all of the dimensions during training, but leave them unspecified. The dimensions of the tensors you feed must be compatible with the shapes of the placeholders, but you are not forced to specify all of the placeholder dimensions in the first place. Here, try putting "None" in place of self.n_steps.

Comment: I tried doing it before posting the question actually, but at some point during the creation of the model, I have `tf.split(0, self.n_input, self.x)`. When I don't know/fix `self.n_input`, I put instead `self.x.get_shape()[1]` (`tf.split(0, self.x.get_shape()[1], self.x)`). However, I get the following error: `TypeError: Expected int for argument 'num_split' not Dimension(None).`.

Answer (score 2):

When you define your varible, I suggest you to write it as following

```
[None, None, n_input]
```

instead of:

```
[None, new_sequence_length=50, n_input]
```

It works in my case. I hope it helps

Comment: I tried it (cf. comments on the initial post), but it doesn't work in my case because of the `tf.split` function which takes as input the number of splits required, which is `None` with this solution.